# Does Stack Exchange have a place for open-ended questions and/or discussion?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Within the Stack Exchange structure is there a place for discussions and general sharing of information?

In addition to specific questions and their answers I'd love to have a place where I can learn what tools folks are using and see open-ended discussions but SE doesn't really seem to include that. Am I missing something?

A couple of examples that currently active:

- [What are your network-related regular expressions?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/446/what-are-your-network-related-regular-expressions)
- [Which Python modules are you using for network management and automation?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/489/which-python-modules-are-you-using-for-network-management-and-automation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are certainly interesting discussions in their own right — roundtable discussions which are fun to bandy about with your colleagues; they may even be educational — but frankly, this isn't what *we* do.

Take a look at the new /about page that lays out the purpose of having this site in the first place:

[**About Network Engineering SE**](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/about)

We get a lot of requests to use Stack Exchange as a way to vote on a variety of other… *stuff.* Sharing your favorite regular expressions (or your favorite Python modules or books/blogs/tricks/tips/etc) would certainly make for an interesting compilation. But questions that elicit open-ended contributions, discussions, and debates can't really be properly "answered" in *this* type of Q&A format. That's actually *by design.*

We're not suggesting these questions should never be asked anywhere. Some questions actually *need* the type of discussion and collaboration you seek; there's nothing wrong with that. But these questions are simply better suited to a threaded discussion forum. There are certainly plenty of them on the Internet — **it's simply not what *we* do.**

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks