# Are questions on config examples welcomed?

Tags: discussion

Whilst many people are asking theoretical questions "How should I best set up IGP metrics for this topology....blah blah blah" no one seems to be asking for specific config examples (which are vendor specific).

Can I ask the question "How to configure L2PTv3 tunnel between two router LAN interfaces, both on Cisco IOS?" for example?

Answer (score 14):

I would vote that yes, config examples are on topic/welcome.

They are the type of question that is easily answerable in SE's Q/A format, and the type of questions that would drive search engine traffic our way.

The theoretical questions can sometimes lead into more of a discussion, instead of a cold hard "yes/no" or "this is how to do xyz".  Which, to my understanding, is not how SE is designed to function.

See [this](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/does-stack-exchange-have-a-place-for-open-ended-questions-and-or-discussion) meta question.  It appears that the consensus there was that focus should be on directly answerable questions.   Which, to me, config examples/questions are a perfect example of questions with direct answers.

Answer (score 8):

Also I think that config examples in answers are very welcome.

- The OP and interested readers would immediately be able to try and modify the solution
- It can easily be verified if the solution would really work (or if it might have been a guess)
- Google and others lead users to our site who search for specific commands

It would be good to keep code in answers reduced to the actual topic, so no complete device configs but the complete set of problem related settings. Mentioning model and OS version would be good, and it would great if somebody would be able to tell to which platforms or versions the solution applies.